# Hiw to use Held_keys for two different keys

Tags: python, replace, command, key, ursina

I have written a code where I want to use the command held_keys for two different keys but if I write:

```
shift = held_keys['shift']
two = held_keys['q']
```

the first command will be replaced by the second how can I prevent this, so I can still use this command but for both keys.

I really have no idea what to try so I could really use every kind of help